# connection with Excel

Tags: .net

I'm trying to get dynamic connection from external file with excel vi C#
My code is

```
Excel.connection objconn;
objconn=null;
Excel.workconnection wc=objconn.AddfromFile("C:\\test.odc");
```

when i do debuging the compiler give me exception 
Object reference not set to an instance an object on the last statement
please help me

Answer (score 0):

That is because your object is null. You actuallty set it to null explicitly in the preceding line.

If Excel.connection is a class with a default constructor, you can do:

```
objconn = new Excel.connection();
```

(Otherwise, modify appropiately to match the correct constructor).

Comment: Thank you, but the Connection not Class but it's interface and when I write Excel.connection objconn;
      Excel.workconnection wc=objconn.AddfromFile("C:\\test.odc");
the compiler give me you should assign initial value to objconn 
but the connection here from Microsoft.Office.Interop.connection
type and I couldn't know how can I assign the initial value to it

Answer (score 0):

you set objconn to null , so it's normal to have Object reference not set to an instance error when executing `objconn.AddfromFile("C:\\test.odc");`

Comment: Thank you, but the Connection not Class but it's interface and when I write Excel.connection objconn;
      Excel.workconnection wc=objconn.AddfromFile("C:\\test.odc");
the compiler give me you should assign initial value to objconn 
but the connection here from Microsoft.Office.Interop.connection
type and I couldn't know how can I assign the initial value to it

Answer (score 0):

```
        //Create a new Excel object
        var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        //Grab a reference to the current WorkBook
        var WB = app.ThisWorkbook;
        //Add a connection to the WorkBook
        WB.Connections.AddFromFile("C:\\test.odc");
```